# Django React Image wont display

Tags: django, reactjs, image, django-rest-framework

So I recently was trying to deploy my website and I was able to get everything working. However, the images are broken for some reason. I can actually add images to the database fine [(easily able to add and change the image itself)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3aa5.png). However, when I click on the link I go nowhere instead of seeing the image and just see the part of my site that pops up whenever the URL entered isn't part of the API [(no error, instead nothing basically shows up)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Un9Js.png). The strange part is that the uploaded images actually get added to my images folder in my project but it seems like Django can't find them afterwards [(you can see the image is in the database in my images folder)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFFUO.png). [Here is how my project is laid out and:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yg2oN.png) Here is some of my code:
**SETTINGS.PY**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'staticfiles')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'build/static'),
]
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
'DEFAULT_AUTHETICATION_CLASSES': [
    'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication'
]
}

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR),'EZtrade')
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'build')],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
]
```

**URLS.PY**

```
urlpatterns = [
path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls')),
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('api/', include('articles.api.urls')),
path('rest-auth/', include('rest_auth.urls')),
path('rest-auth/registration/', include('rest_auth.registration.urls')),
re_path('.*',TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html')),
url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', serve, {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT,})
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**API URLS**

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'articles', ArticleViewSet, basename='articles')
router.register(r'trade', TradeViewSet, basename='trade')
router.register(r'users', UserDataViewSet, basename='users')
urlpatterns = router.urls + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**MODEL**

```
class Article(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
content = models.TextField()
image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'images', blank=True)
createdBy = models.CharField(max_length=120)
traded = models.BooleanField(default=False)
city = models.CharField(max_length=120)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

**VIEWS.PY**

```
class ArticleViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
serializer_class = ArticleSerializer
queryset = Article.objects.all()
filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend,filters.SearchFilter]
filterset_fields = ['createdBy','traded']
search_fields = ['title']
authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,) # Add this line
permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
def get_permissions(self):
    if self.action == 'list' or self.action == 'retrieve':
        return [AllowAny(), ]        
    return super(ArticleViewSet, self).get_permissions() 
def patch(self, request, pk):
    testmodel_object = self.get_object(pk)
    serializer = TestModelSerializer(testmodel_object, data=request.data, partial=True)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return JsonResponse(code=201, data=serializer.data)
    return JsonResponse(code=400, data="wrong parameters")
```

**SERIALIZERS.PY**

```
class ArticleSerializer(PatchModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = Article
    fields = ('id','title','content','image','createdBy','traded','city')
```

I have tried many different things and have not been able to find anything else like this on the internet since I dont even get an error when trying to access the image. Im pretty stuck with this so if anyone could help that would be awsome!

Answer (score 0):

you have to make an another serializer using method and pass image url on that like this

```
class ArticleSerializer(PatchModelSerializer):
    image_url = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_image_url')
    class Meta:
    model = Article
    fields = ('id','title','content','image','image_url','createdBy','traded','city')
    def get_image_url(self, obj):
        return obj.image.url
```

Comment: Hey, I tried adding the serializer but the images are still blank. This is what the field looked like and its basically the same as the image field."image": "http://localhost:8000/media/images/IMG_0017_Mo65tTP.jpg",
        "image_url": "/media/images/IMG_0017_Mo65tTP.jpg",

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that I had to put the re_path at the end since it was overriding my image url.

Answer (score 0):

i just figured out that the problem is in the urls.py file
it's missing some code
here is mine before

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include



    urlpatterns = [
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
        path('api/', include('api.urls'))
    
    ]
```

and here is after i saw this [article](https://overiq.com/django-1-10/handling-media-files-in-django/)

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/', include('api.urls'))

]
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
                          document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```